# How do I open .CDR file with Adobe Illustrator CS3?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, coreldraw

I have a Corel Draw file from a customer and was wondering if we could open this in Adobe Illustrator CS3? I don't know what version the Coreldraw file was created in. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open .CDR files directly (i.e. 'File > Open') in Adobe Illustrator CS3 and I assume other versions (tested with CDR file from CorelDraw version 10).

Another option is to get the customer to save the file from CorelDraw as a PDF which should then open in Illustrator.

Comment: pelms, thanks, I tried that but I get this error 'The file xyz is an unknown format and cannot be opened.' It could be possible that the version this file was created in is one that came after Coreldraw 10.

Comment: Hmmm.. yep version 10 is pretty old now. Can the customer save it in another format for you?

Comment: I'll try but this kind of answers my question. I think we can't open Coreldraw 10+ files in Illustrator CS3. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Illustrator does not open all Corel Draw files.** If you cannot open with Illustrator, here are a couple freeware programs which allow conversion to a format you surely can open:

- [XnConvert](http://www.xnconvert.com/) : exports to several formats  (windows/mac/linux)
- [Uniconvertor](http://sk1project.org/modules.php?name=products&product=uniconvertor): exports to several vector formats (windows/mac/linux)
- [InkScape](http://sourceforge.net/projects/inkscape/): full fledged (thus likely an overkill since you already have illustrator) vector graphics editor (windows only)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to open it by changing the cdr file extension to .eps. Worked for me, but may not work on all.